# Disable scrolling but keep the bar visible

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, scroll

When displaying a popup on a long page I need to disable scrolling.

I've tried 3 solutions but none are acceptable.

### The body: fixed & overflow-y: scroll

```
document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
document.body.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
```

This could have been a good solution, but if I trigger the popup while having already scrolled to the end of the page, the page scrolls back to the top.

### Catch mouswheel event

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", (e) => e.preventDefault());
```

This works but I can still click on the scrollbar and scroll.

### Disable scrollbar and add margin

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
document.body.style.marginRight = '1rem';
```

This didn't add a margin. (and I'm afraid of the issues with different scrollbars width)

EDIT:

I'm trying another solution based on HostListner

```
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  public handleScroll(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

It triggers correctly but doesn't prevent the scroll...

Comment: why do you want the scrollbar visible...

Comment: @Bhuwan because when it disappears it makes the content jump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to calculate the scrollbar width of the browser using

```
var scrollbarWidth = window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth;
```

And when popup is visible add `overflow: hidden` to remove scrolling with `margin-right` equal to the width of scrollbar so that the page does not jump using `Object.assign` like

```
var scrollbarWidth = window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth;
Object.assign(document.body.style, {
  overflow: "hidden",
  marginRight: scrollbarWidth + "px"
});
```

<sub>>>>***Note:*** Make sure your body has `margin:0` by default</sub>

```js
var scrollbarWidth = window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth;
Object.assign(document.body.style, {
  overflow: "hidden",
  marginRight: scrollbarWidth + "px"
});
console.log(document.body.style.marginRight);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the last solution I've tried. Overflow hidden works but marginRight doesn't. I have margin: 0 on body